# Loading Data to Pig with a pipe hyphen pipe |-| delimiter

Tags: regex, apache-pig

When I try to load file.txt to Pig I am getting the following error:

```
pig script failed to validate: java.lang.RuntimeException: could not instantiate 'PigStorage' with arguments '[\|-\|]'
```

A sample line from the file is:

text|-|text|-|text

I am using the following command:

```
bag = LOAD 'file.txt' USING PigStorage('\\|-\\|') AS (v1:chararray, v2:chararray, v3:chararray);
```

Is it the delimiter?  My regex?

Comment: It does not look like PigStorage allows a regex delimiter. Try just `PigStorage('|-|')`.

Comment: Sorry, tried that first and it still throws:  pig script failed to validate: java.lang.RuntimeException: could not instantiate 'PigStorage' with arguments '[|-|]'

Comment: Yeah, so the issue is that the delimiter can only be one byte character, and you have 3: [*delimiter - the **single byte character** that is used to separate fields*](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/PigStorage.html#PigStorage(java.lang.String)). I found one hint regarding that: [*one can always create a new loadfunc and implement his own parsing
(perhaps by extending PigStorage and overriding the parsing bits).*](http://qnalist.com/questions/572/regular-expression-as-delimiter-in-pigstorage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to write a custom LOAD function,you could probably load your records using '-' as the delimiter and then add another step to replace all the '|' in your fields.

```
bag = LOAD 'file.txt' USING PigStorage('-') AS (v1:chararray, v2:chararray, v3:chararray);
bag_new =  FOREACH bag GENERATE 
                    REPLACE(v1,'|','') as v1_new,
                    REPLACE(v2,'|','') as v2_new,
                    REPLACE(v3,'|','') as v3_new;
```